# "is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint", when using the Omit util type

Tags: typescript, higher-order-functions

I'm playing around with creating a higher order function, intended for use in React, but for simplicity this doesn't have any JSX.

Basically, what I'm trying here to achieve here, I have a higher-order-function that is going to inject some required value into a function call.

That is - the function that is passed *into* the HOF is expecting these arguments. And the function that is returned from the HOF will not.

Here's my code:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=39&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgJwCYAUEHswGcoF4oDeAUFFMAJbAA2EAXFFsAuQHYDmA3FCQ+gLYRgAC1ZsAYhj4AJdAGN6jZuy5EAvkSKz0LRlFkIIcYBHjI8UABRgM2eqdQ2sASjwA+KNcxYVRUJCgysmhe5sSkWPyCIuwS-IEKTKIq6r7g0AAiEMwAbhAOXgA8ACpQEAAexixIOASqADRQAKqlFRBVOEXu+ADyfJQFjQ0A1hAg6ABmUJ0+mtq6AO6UQgDKkcKi5gUoLZXVAXLB2K4W4yz0Vo70KC647tduhDwGwACuCCyWntgATPSZOXlDlgCoEgQ0UK4bu5iDxSFodMAoCwIPMgVArqEoAA6HFfLDfBoRATrGKSeJQABEQggVCo6ApUFUHFhUGebw+pwsyNRjicPHUKXhukC9nMi2Eq2J0TYFn0hmM9iczI0IsQSAsYTIlBo9CpNLpFLUSu4GiIAHoLUVqR4MAAjGh8BjkPhgKjkcbkPKzBFQOAsdDCLJWjb4LY7Np7UGOY6sMAvYB-LLkXL5bAgg6OcGQjG3TVs96PUikHFY2PxuosolRUSxaRyXXU2n0-kcABW3HUQA)

```js
type CardProps = {
  title: string; 
  somethingFromHoc: string; 
}

const createCard = (props: CardProps) => props; 

type HocProps = {
  somethingFromHoc: string; 
}

type DerivedProps<T extends {}, U extends T> = Omit<U, keyof T>; 


const withSomething = <P extends HocProps>(fn: (props: P) => P) => {
  return (props2: DerivedProps<HocProps, P>) => {

    const newProps : P = { ...props2, somethingFromHoc: "hello" }; //Error!
    return fn(newProps)
  }
}

const HocCard = withSomething(createCard);


HocCard({
  title: "hello"
});
```

I suspect that the issue is around the `DerivedProps`.

That is, the DerivedProps is meant to be 'Just an object that is everything that was in the original props type, except those values that were created by the HOC'.

When I then merge them together again, I'm expecting that `HocProps + DerivedProps = OrignalProps` is always true.

Am I wrong on this?

I can always supress this error with:

```
const newProps : P = { ...props2, somethingFromHoc: "hello" } as P;
```

but is there a scenario where this would be erroneous?

Here is a simplified version of the problem:

```js
const anotherThing = <P extends HocProps>(input: DerivedProps<HocProps, P>): P =>{
  return {
    ...input,
    somethingFromHoc: "hello"
  };j 
}
```

Comment: This looks like it might be a design limitation of TypeScript: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35858